# Random item with probability from SQL table in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out how to select a random item with it's own given chance from a table of values like this:

```
itemlottery (npcid, item, chance) VALUES (9100100, 1402011, 167)
itemlottery (npcid, item, chance) VALUES (9100100, 1041082, 267)
itemlottery (npcid, item, chance) VALUES (9100100, 1322003, 1668)
itemlottery (npcid, item, chance) VALUES (9100100, 1061033, 89)
itemlottery (npcid, item, chance) VALUES (9100100, 1051001, 89)
itemlottery (npcid, item, chance) VALUES (9100100, 2000005, 188983)
```

So basically I can get the item and chances from SQL, but would it be better to hard code it in java?

Anyway, those are the values that I need (the list actually contains more than 50+ items).

Now my question is how can I read these values then generate a random item based on those chances in Java?

This is for a game NPC, what would give players a random lottery item based on the chances.

Edit: 
You HAVE to get one item and you can't get multiple items.
the higher the chance, the more likely it is to get that item.

Comment: In this dataset, is the greater the chance value the greater are the odds to find that object or the other way around? Is it possible to get zero or multiple objects?

Comment: I edited my original post with the corrections @SimonBerthiaume

Comment: @Forgets . . . Your chances are so disproportionate that you might as well choose the last one all the time.

Comment: @GordonLinoff this was just a short glimpse I posted, the original sql has well over 100 items with chances. I just included the highest value being 189k and the lowest value being 89.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in MySQL with `rand()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, (@sum := @sum + chance) as cume_chance
      from t cross join
           (select @sum := 0, @r := rand()) params
     ) t 
where @r < cume_chance / @sum and
      @r >= (cume_chance - chance) / @sum;
```

The reason the `rand()` is calculated into a variable is so the function is only evaluated once.  When the outer `where` is run, `@sum` should contain the total sum of `chance`.  An alternative is to calculate it explicitly using a subquery.

Comment: Is that in java? It looks like a sql script. I was hoping to make a function to get the chances for the item id's and give the item randomly

Comment: @Forgets . . . Your question is tagged SQL.  I didn't realize you wanted the solution in java.  The solution is the same . . . accumulate the chances and then use a random number generator.  Unless you have a really slow bandwidth to the database the performance should be pretty similar.

Comment: yeah sorry i'm new to this, I also tagged java. should I re-post in java tag only?